# Absolute positioning with overflow auto to html

Tags: html, css, web, position

I have a HTML page, and overflow is auto for HTML tag.
I am trying to add an absolute positioned div, whose height may vary. like a custom combo-box.
so problem is when the combobox is very near to footer such that the gap between combo-box and footer is less than the height of div, the div is not at all displayed in IE7. However it works fine in FF and scroll bar appears on the page. [image: IE it does not show div]

[image: FF it shows the div.]

Can someone pls suggest something?

Comment: can you add a fiddle link for your issue with code snippets?

Comment: Provide a link or even better, a fiddle demonstrating the core problem. You could also consider stop developing for IE7 (Google stopped supporting it in august 2011) or try one of the libraries that tries to fixs some of IE7 many issues (e.g. ie7-js: https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)

Comment: Please provide some code snippets, a working example or a link to the site which this is being used on. That way we can help you. I wouldn't recommend that you stop developing for IE7 just yet.